# Callout labels does not seem to work in multiple curves, why?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have tried this plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Callout[(Exp[-γ ρ^2] /. γ -> #), "γ=" <> ToString[#],  
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Italic}] & /@ {0, 0.1, 1, 4, 9}], {ρ, 0, 1}, PlotRange 
-> {-0.05, 1.2}, AspectRatio -> 0.8, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, 
{Black, Dashing[{0.02, 0.01}]}, {Black, Dashing[Medium]}, {Black, 
Dashing[Small]}, {Black, Dashing[Tiny]}}, FrameLabel -> {Style["ρ", 18], 
Style["A(ρ)", 22]},GridLines -> Automatic, RotateLabel -> True(*,FrameStyle\
[Rule]Directive[Plain,16,FontFamily\[Rule]"Times\New Roman"]*)]
```

This is the result:

[image]

However, the labels of each curve should be in bold and italic.

I know and have checked that for a single curve it works. Why not for several ones?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In my experience, `Callout` does seem to have a number of significant bugs. As you observe, styling doesn't seem to work if you want to just accept the default positioning. You'll find that it will work if you position the callout labels manually. Automatic placement of the labels can be strange, too. I think `Callout` just wasn't quite ready for prime time yet; hopefully it will be fixed in the next maintenance update.

Comment: Other options such as `CalloutStyle` or `Appearance` do not work either.

Comment: Maybe it works now, but I haven't received the update yet. The Quick Revision History says for V11.0.1: "ListPlot labeling and callout functionality now exhibit expected behavior".

Comment: I have just updated to 11.0.1. Unfortunately, I still obtain the same plot as above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this modification

```
Callout[(Exp[-γ ρ^2] /. γ -> #), 
  Style["γ=" <> ToString[#], Bold, Italic]]
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, styling the label straightforwardly seems to be a valid solution...